# ASP.Net MVC application access to other servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have an ASP.Net MVC application (website), just a straight web app. The URL it needs to connect to is an ASP.Net WebAPI2 web service on port 14015. The MVC application is calling the Web service anonymously using a WebClient class; the web service is secured by limiting which IPs can connect to it. There is no authorization mode to access except by IP.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    //****************************
    // We make the web service call like this:
    //****************************
    string url = @"http://secure.example.com:14015/lms/SSOKey/1158341";
    string key = client.DownloadString(url);
    //****************************
    // Then we append the returned key to build the full URL. This URL is used
    // in the View to build a link button.
    //****************************
    string login_url = @"http://192.168.1.1/tc/login.do?uid=" + key;
    login_url = login_url.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    //****************************
    // Pass the URL to the view to build the link button
    //****************************
    ViewBag.LoginURL = login_url;
}
```

I can access the URL from a browser on the server where the MVC application is published, however, the call is unsuccessful. Any ideas how I may find out why this won't connect??

Comment: Please provide a little more detail.

Comment: Like WHAT? I don't know what else to give.

Comment: CONTEXT...For one, the nature of the application. Did you build a screen scrapper, a file down-loader, etc. Is the WebClient calling the MVC Application? Does the MVC application call the WebClient? Are the WebClient and MVC Application one in the same? Does the WebClient access the URL anonymously? Is the MVC application authenticated? Without knowing more I can give you at least three or four answers.

Comment: @MB34 what kind of application is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code solved the problem.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Since we limit access by IP Addresses, very low security risk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the code inside of a controller and the users have to logon to your web app, than this code should give you what you need:

```
string currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
```

If your users use your web app anonymously currentUser will be blank.

Comment: We don't use the Identity classes in our application. We use a ticket based logon process and store a session variable. So this would not help.

Comment: @MB34, in that case just grab the session variable: string  <your variable> = Session["<your ticket number>"].ToString();

Comment: Well, I already KNOW that. I need to understand if the MVC application calling the web service uses some kind of specific user. I do NOT need the logged in user from the application, itself. Please read my edits above.